# EmberJS no model was found

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The first time using EmberJS with MongoDB backend. Trying connect to a HTTP Server.

Chrome console shows:
Error while loading route: Error: No model was found for '0'

**app.js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
  this.resource('users');
  this.resource('customers');
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter,
});
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api'
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('users');
  }

});

var attr = DS.attr;

App.Users = DS.Model.extend({
  fname: attr(),
  lname: attr(),
  nname: attr(),
  email: attr(),
  role: attr()
});
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "538c00932d22d69a46130a47",
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "_id": "538c00932d22d69a46130a48",
    "fname": "Jane",
    "lname": "Doe",
    "email": "jane.doe@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared a JSBin with your code and it works: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xozar/1/edit

The only change I've made is with the **_id property**. The Application Serializer is searching for **id property**. If you want to customize the primary key of your model you should override the default model serializer behaviour:

`App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});`

Anyway, I think that the naming conventions of Ember prefer the models in singular: http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it to work if I use a fixture adapter rather than a REST adapter. The REST adapter still return could not find the model even though I change the correct naming conventions. The JSON was copied off of Chrome console, so I know that the API is being call.